# Object-Oriented Javascript custom addEvent method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

I have a question regarding developing object-orientated javascript and parsing variables. Please see [this blog by net.tutsplus - The Basics of Object-Oriented JavaScript](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/) for more info.

I have the following code which creates an event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tools.addEvent('.someButton', 'click', user.getUserDetails);
)};

var tools = {
    addEvent: function(to, type, fn) {
        $(to).live(type, fn);
    }
}

var user = {
    getUserDetails: function(userID) {
        console.log(userID);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it calls the `addEvent` method with three variables; the DOM element to attach the event to, the type of the event and the function to run when the event is triggered.

The issue I am having is parsing a variable to the getUserDetails method and I know of 2 options:

1. I could obviously have 1 line of code at the start which could check an attribute of the sender. For example, the `.someButton` could have an attribute `userID="12345"`. However, this is not ideal because the function is run from several different places - meaning this check is not always available (and the code is harder to manage).
2. A better option could be to have another method like `user.willGetUserDetails` and use this method to get the attribute `userID` from the DOM. This could be run from anywhere on the page, and would call `getUserDetails` after getting the `userID`. Whenever the user details comes from within another function, we would simply call `getUserDetails` directly.
3. What would be ideal, is if I could amend the code above to pass a variable directly - even an undefined one. Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: If you want to "parse" a variable, just use `JSON.stringify(variable);`. Also, do not use `.live()` since it was removed from jQuery since 1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add one more argument to your addEvent code that accepts data to pass to the event.

```
var tools = {
    addEvent: function(to, type, data, fn) {
        if ($.isFunction(data)) {
            fn = data;
            data = {};
        }
        $(to).live(type, data, fn);
    }
}
```

Also, i'd suggest using delegate instead, or .on in 1.7+

```
var tools = {
    addEvent: function(to, type, data, fn) {
        if ($.isFunction(data)) {
            fn = data;
            data = {};
        }
        $(document).delegate(to, type, data, fn);
    }
}
```

or

```
var tools = {
    addEvent: function(to, type, data, fn) {
        if ($.isFunction(data)) {
            fn = data;
            data = {};
        }
        $(document).on(type, to, data, fn);
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tools.addEvent('.someButton', 'click', {userID: theuserid}, user.getUserDetails);
)};

var user = {
    getUserDetails: function(event) {
        console.log(event.data.userID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Fantastic answer and so fast too. Needless to say, it works as I hoped. Thanks

Comment: +1 for adding `delegate` example for pre 1.7 as it still is heavily used and is very useful information for future users.

Comment: @Patrick It would also be a good idea to add one more argument that you can use as a context instead of `document` if you aren't using the `.live` version.